# use session object in grails navigation api

Tags: session, grails

I'm using the navigation api from the grails platform core.  I'm trying to get a session variable to be used in the title of one of the links (a person's name).  According to the docs in the section visibility and status:

```
The closures receive a delegate which resolves the following standard Grails properties:

grailsApplication
pageScope
session
request
controllerName
actionName
flash
params
```

That seems to indicate I would have the session available in navigation.groovy.  In my navigation.groovy I have a menu defined as:

```
import grails.util.GrailsWebUtil
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityRequestHolder
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils


navigation = {
    def isBF = { ->
        SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted('ROLE_BF')
    }
    def indexTitleName = {  ->
        return session.id
    }
    app {
        home controller:'birthFamily', action:'contactInfo'
    }
    birthFamily {
        index(titleText:indexTitleName())
}
```

}

Program will not start and generates this error:

```
| Error 2013-10-18 08:16:57,286 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Exception evaluating property 'id' for java.util.ArrayList, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: id for class: org.grails.plugin.platform.conventions.DSLBlockCommand
Message: Exception evaluating property 'id' for java.util.ArrayList, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: id for class: org.grails.plugin.platform.conventions.DSLBlockCommand
    Line | Method
->>   12 | doCall                           in NrfaNavigation$_run_closure1_closure3
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     28 | doCall                           in NrfaNavigation$_run_closure1_closure6
|     53 | __newBlock . . . . . . . . . . . in org.grails.plugin.platform.conventions.StandardDSLDelegate
|     66 | methodMissing                    in     ''
|     25 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . . . in NrfaNavigation$_run_closure1
|     46 | build                            in org.grails.plugin.platform.conventions.StandardDSLBuilder
|     31 | evaluate . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.grails.plugin.platform.conventions.DSLEvaluator
|    280 | registerNavigation               in org.grails.plugin.platform.navigation.NavigationImpl
```

If I replace 'session.id' with 'hello world' all is well.

Comment: how did you add fullName to the session ? are you sure it's in there?

Comment: Even if I try session.id or session.toString() the error shows up.  The session variable just isn't present.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://grailsrocks.github.io/grails-platform-core/guide/nav.html#using_navigation_dsl) you need to create closures:

> Note how the Closures are "def"'d in the script to make them reusable
>   and reachable within the DSL
>
> The closures receive a delegate which resolves the following standard
>   Grails properties:
>
> - grailsApplication
> - pageScope
> - session
> - request
> - controllerName
> - actionName
> - flash params

So you need something like:

```
def indexTitleName = {
  return session.fullName
}

navigation = {
  account {
    index(titleText:indexTitleName)
  }
}
```

**Edit**

It seems that the closure it's applied only when you use the `visible` attribute. To get the session, chage your navigation class:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils
def indexTitleName = {
  def webUtils = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest()
  def session = webUtils.getCurrentRequest().getSession()
  return session.fullName
}
```

Comment: No luck.  First I had to declare index(titleText:indexTitleName()) with parenthesis to get valid output.  Without () I was getting a cryptic closure name like AppNavigation$_run_closure1_closure3@1caa59e6.  After getting around that if I try return session.id the error is Message: Exception evaluating property 'id' for java.util.ArrayList, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: id for class: org.grails.plugin.platform.conventions.DSLBlockCommand

Comment: Ok I've revised the code in my original post to include a complete navigation.groovy.  The program will not start if session.id is present.

Comment: Also I included the 'def isBF' closure because that actually does work without any issues.

Comment: Can you try declaring your closure out of the navigation block? Comparing your code with mine I think that this is the difference.

Comment: A different error this time when moving the def outside navigation: Error 2013-10-18 12:56:55,997 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: No such property: session for class: AppNavigation
Message: No such property: session for class: AppNavigation
    Line | Method
->>    7 | doCall                           in AppNavigation$_run_closure1

Comment: hmm I will do an example, wait for it :-)

Comment: Any luck with this?  I've just burned another hour and still can't get any of the claimed grails objects that are supposed to be available to work.  The documentation even states springSecurityService.principal instanceof String as an example, but that doesn't compile for me.

Comment: Ok, it seems that this closure can be used only in the visible attribute, see my edit to get the session.

Comment: Just thought in an easier way: customize the rendering of the menu, using session directly, since this is available in the GSP. Check the example in the docs - http://grailsrocks.github.io/grails-platform-core/ref/Navigation%20Tags/menu.html